# How to find the value from a row of table depending on the row of a button I clicked

Tags: javascript, dom

No jQuery involve pls. I am just started learning javascript.
I want to find the class='id' of the table when I clicked on the class='detail' button.
I manage to point to class='id' but I can't get the value out of it, why?

```js
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("detail");
for (var i in button) {
  button[i].onclick = function() {
    var row = this.closest("tr");
    var id = row.getElementsByClassName("id");
    var value = id.innerText;
    console.log(id);
    console.log(value); //show undefined here 
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="id">123</td>
      <td class="name">abc</td>
      <td><button class="detail">detail</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="id">456</td>
      <td class="name">def</td>
      <td><button class="detail">detail</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

where would need to change? I must use class here, as the table generated through javascript. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns `HTMLCollection` containing multiple matching elements. Like an array, you can access the first element in the collection with `[0]`

```js
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("detail");
for (var i in button) {
  button[i].onclick = function () {
    var row = this.closest("tr");
    var id = row.getElementsByClassName("id");
    var value = id[ 0 ].innerText;
    console.log(id);
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="id">123</td>
      <td class="name">abc</td>
      <td><button class="detail">detail</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="id">456</td>
      <td class="name">def</td>
      <td><button class="detail">detail</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks!! Been finding solution through all over the internet to get to this point, but just the last small step.....

Comment: You could also use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to only return the first matching element